# Stuck on Discrete distribution having an issue with finishing the problem

Tags: java, arrays

[Here is what I am suppose to be getting.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9hkIH.png)

[This is what I am actually getting.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oybMu.png)

Write a program DiscreteDistribution.java that takes an integer command-line argument m, followed by a sequence of positive integer command-line arguments a1,a2,…,an, and prints m random indices (separated by whitespace), choosing each index i with probability proportional to ai.

So far I have

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // number of random indices
    int m = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);

    // read in frequency of occurrence of n values
    int n = args.length;
    int[] freq = new int[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        freq[i] = Integer.parseInt(args[i]);
    }

    // compute total count of all frequencies
    int total = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        total += freq[i];
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
        // generate random integer with probability proportional to frequency
        int r = (int) ((total) * Math.random() - 1);   // integer in [0, total)
        int sum = 0;
        int event = -1;
        for (int i = 0; i < n && sum <= r; i++) {
            sum += freq[i];
            event = i;
            System.out.println(freq[i]);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Java is to Javascript as Pain is to Painting, or Ham is to Hamster. They are completely different. It is highly recommended that aspiring coders try to learn the name of the language they're attempting to write code in. When you post a question, please tag it appropriately - this lets those with knowledge of the language you need help with to see your question.

Comment: I understand. I am fairly new to this and I didn't know that. Thank you for clearing that up for me.

Comment: Can you please share an example input String array `args`?

Comment: You said you had an issue finishing the problem, but you didn't really say what that issue was.

Comment: I added some images to help.

Comment: Well, you're going to all this trouble of finding `event`, the index that the random number `r` represents, but you never do anything with it. Perhaps it should be getting printed out somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under the assumption that I understand your problem correctly, then you can use the following algorithm to produce `m` random numbers in the range 1 to `n`  according to the given frequencies:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {

    // number of random indices
    int m = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);

    // read in frequency of occurrence of n values
    int n = args.length;
    int[] freq = new int[n];
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
      freq[i] = Integer.parseInt(args[i]);
    }

    // compute total count of all frequencies
    int total = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
      total += freq[i];
    }
    double[] summedProbabilities = new double[n];
    for (int i = 1; i < summedProbabilities.length; i++) {
      final double probability = freq[i] / (double) total;
      summedProbabilities[i] = summedProbabilities[i -1] + probability;

    }
    for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
      // generate random integer with probability proportional to frequency
      double randomProbability = Math.random();
      int i = 1;
      while (randomProbability > summedProbabilities[i]) {
        i++;
      }
      System.out.print(i + " ");
      if (j % 10 == 0) {
        System.out.println();
      }
    }
  }
```

I strongly suggest you to refactor the code in a way that you use methods to calculate small pieces and compose it then.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class DiscreteDistribution{
   public static void main(String[] args) {
   // takes in number of times we must loop to print indices
    int m = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
   // set the array size to the number of input from command line 
   //minus the first input
   //because we are not considering the input at args[0]
    int [] n = new int[args.length-1];
   
   // cSum to store the cummulatives
    int [] cSum = new int[args.length];

   // to store an array of random generated 
   //number of size m
    int [] rand = new int[m];
    int count = 1;
    int cCount = 1;
    int sum = 0; // to add the inputs n;

   // to store user input in an array in n ignoring the first input
    for(int i =0; i < n.length; i++)
    {
        n[i] = Integer.parseInt(args[count]);
        count++;
    }

    //stores the cummulatives of n in cSum
    for(int j = 0; j < n.length; j++)
    {
        sum = sum + n[j];
        cSum[j+1] = sum;
    }

    //generate a random number and stores in rand representing the //probabilites
    for(int p = 0; p < m; p++) {    
            int r = (int)(1+Math.random()*cSum[cSum.length-1]);
            rand[p] = r;
     }

   // loop from 0 to m to print the indices of n;
     for(int s = 0; s < m; s++) {
        
        //prints the indices corresponding to the condition
        for(int q = 1; q < n.length; q++) {
            if(rand[s] <= cSum[q-1]) {
                System.out.print(q+" ");
            }
            
        }
        
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).